# HTTP error 403 when using Confluent Kafka REST Proxy

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-rest

I use Confluent Kafka REST Proxy to send messages to Apache Kafka. 
I set up basic authentication on the REST Proxy and whenever I submit a HTTP request to the proxy, I get the 403 HTTP Error !role.

The proxy requires Zookeeper, Kafka and Schema Registry to be running. I didn't configure any security on these services.

Without authentication, the proxy works and delivers messages to Kafka successfully.
How to I troubleshoot this problem? I spent multiple hours on that problem and I still can't fix it.

Comment: Show all relevant confiig files and refer. https://docs.confluent.io/current/confluent-security-plugins/kafka-rest/introduction.html#confluentsecurityplugins-kafaka-rest-security-plugin

Comment: @buahahaXD You probably need to look at implementing this plugin provided by confluent - https://docs.confluent.io/current/confluent-security-plugins/kafka-rest/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Check following:

1. Firewall allow the service or port
2. Is there any antivirus block the service or port
3. Rights given on kafka, confluent folder & respective log directory to kafka user.